# In Yii2 dirtyAttributes() get only string fields? Need to take number fields and relation fields

Tags: php, yii2

I get dirty attributes in after save method. but it only gives fields which are in string type. Not gets fields are in Number type and foreign key fields.

Comment: dirtyAttributes  refers to changed attributes(either massively assigned from POST or single assignment) that require a database update. use `$model->getDirtyAttributes()` to get attribute=>value pairs for all changed values before you save your record/data

Comment: $this->changedAttributes = $this->getDirtyAttributes(); i set this in beforesave(). then in after save i use folowing.
foreach($this->changedAttributes as $field => $value){
//execute code
}
but this takes only text, date and varchar type attributes

Comment: $getDirtyAttributes() uses strict comparison to check for updated values. what is the datatype of your numeric values in POST?

Comment: the fields which taken as dirty attributes, model data type is string. from table they are varchar, text and date. others which not taken as dirty attribute are set as number and interger.

Comment: when i'm change the datatype from db table float to varchar it taken as dirty attribute